# Get Rank from list of object depending upon some condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, sorting, collections

I have list of object of class which contain totalScore as one property.I want to get rank of Team depending upon totalscore of team.Here is the list of object I called it as List data= new List();

so data contain object of scoreboard class with total score property.
I need rank of team depending upon totalscore.Here is the code that I try but it give result like Rank=1,2,2,3 but I need Rank=1,2,2,4 like this.

```
data.OrderByDescending(x => x.totalScore).GroupBy(x => x.totalScore)
    .SelectMany((g, i) => g.Select(e => new { data = e.Rank = i + 1 }))
    .ToList();
```

The data list contain unique team but there total score may be same so same totalscore team must be in one rank. please help me!

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but, what you want to design is a way to sort a list by rank (based on their total score). However; if two teams are tied on score, they must share the rank (e.g. second place), and then no team can be third place? If no team had equal score, the sequential order would be correct?

Comment: Two team can have same score.Like t1=100,t2=100,t1=50 then Rank will be like Rank=1,1,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to update the list in-place:

```
int i = 0;
decimal? prevValue = null;
foreach(var item in data.OrderByDescending(x => x.totalScore))
{
    item.Rank = prevValue == item.totalScore ? i : ++i;

    prevValue = item.totalScore;
}
```

Comment: In front end I need to to send data list and I have Rank property in score board class how should I assign this Rank to it? will it give result like Rank=1,2,2,4?

Comment: You are sending Rank as separate variable in list but I need to send Rank in same List.

Comment: here what if two team(two object  have totalscore same) have same score?what will be the Rank?

Comment: [
  {
    "Rank": 1,
    "SrNo": 1,
    "Name": "xxx",
    "taskCompleted": "42",
    "totalScore": 466
  },
  {
    "Rank": 2,
    "SrNo": 2,
    "Name": "xx",
    "taskCompleted": "10",
    "totalScore": 117
  },
  {
   ** "Rank": 3,**
    "SrNo": 0,
    "Name": "checked",
    "taskCompleted": "1",
    "totalScore": 117
  },
  {
   ** "Rank": 3,**
    "SrNo": 3,
    "Name": "xxx",
    "taskCompleted": "8",
    "totalScore": 99
  }
]

Comment: @KrishnaChavan Ohh. ++i and i++ issue. I think this should do it. Try the edit.

Comment: Yes it works better now thanks @user3185569.You are genius :)

Answer (score 0):

A different notation (which I prefer for readability) but essentially the same answer as provided by `user3185569`.

```
var i = 1;
var results = (from d in data orderby d.totalScore descending select new { Obj = d, Rank = i++ } ).ToList();
```